# Export an SVG with images and text data

Tags: svg

I'm trying to export an SVG with some MySQL data (images, text) but i'm really having some trouble here.

The basic : I'm doing a circle, divided in 7 parts, where I want to put a logo + some text inside each part.

Result needed :

[image: result1]

I figured out that SVG Crowbar was the ultimate way to export them.. Though, as i'm using some server-stored images, when the export is done, no images are rendered :
[image: result exported]

This is how I display data in each part :

```html
  <image x="270" y="50" xlink:href=/management-rings/web/assets/logos_bc/logo_ange.png height="75" width="75"/>
  <foreignObject x="160" y="140" width="140" height="75">
   <div style="height: 75px; width: 140px; position: absolute; z-index: 8; text-align: center;">
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="text">
     ANGE<br>
    </p>
   </div>  
  </foreignObject>
```

I'm pretty much clueless right now. How to render properly these images when exporting the svg?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Presumably the problem is the relative URLs in the exported SVG. Why can you not modify those URLs so that they are absolute?

Comment: I'll also go against the relative path.
You forgot `"` around the `xlink:href` attribute's value, in the snippet you don't show us how is your root svg defined, it may also miss some namespace declarations.
Finally, note that if you are displaying your svg image from an HTML `<img>`tag,  you won't be able to load external resources, i.e you'll need to convert your images to dataURI version and append this inside your svg markup. *Ps: Wouldn't it be easier to create an svg version of your image and use `<use>` elements instead of raster images?*

Comment: Yep, problem was relative paths. Thanks guys!